# Error when use Pointer-to-Pointer

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pointers

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
Today, i did some research on pointer, i found error when try to point to a pointer from the orther.
Error occured at this line:
    char *cPP = &cP;
when try to read address of cP and put on cPP. Visual Studio announced:

```
a value of type "char **" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"
```

Can you explain this?

### And how can i fix this error?

```
#define   stop __asm nop
int main()
{
    char a = 'A';
    char *cP = &a;
    char *cPP = &cP;
    stop
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `char **cPP = &cP;`?

Comment: Change `cPP` to `char **cPP = &cP;`.  Each time you add a level of indirection, you need a new `*`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define   stop __asm nop
int main()
{
    char a = 'A';
    char *cP = &a;
    char **cPP = &cP;
    stop
    return 0;
}
```

You must have 2 ** to define pointer to a pointer (* to *)

Comment: _`#define   stop __asm nop`_ Clever idea ;)